# Intersection of self-shrinkers

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, parabolic-pde, gradient-flows

I have a problem regarding a statement in the paper [Smooth compactness of self-shrinkers](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2594) by Colding and Minicozzi.

In the article, they define a surface $\Sigma$ in $\mathbb R^3$ to be a self-shrinker if its mean curvature $H$ and the outer normal $n$ satisfy
$$H=\frac{\langle x,n\rangle}2,$$
where $x$ is the position vector. In its corollary, it asserts, "Every self-shrinker must intersect the closed ball bounded by the spherical self-shrinker, which follows from the maximum principle since the associated MCF’s both disappear at the same point in space and time $(0,0).$"

I think the spherical self-shrink is the sphere centered at the origin with radius $2,$ which is a self-shrinker by definition. However, I don't understand how to use the maximum principle to derive that it intersects with any other self-shrinkers. Does this follows by something like avoidance principle for MCF? (But I think intersecting at the singularity doesn't violate that principle...)

Any ideas or comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This is a well-known argument in MCF. One can show that if $\Sigma_1$, $\Sigma_2$ are both properly immersed self-shrinkers and one of them is compact, then the must intersect.

To see this, assume the contrary that $\Sigma_1$, $\Sigma_2$ are disjoint. Since one of them is compact and the other properly immersed, the Euclidean distance between them
$$ d_0(\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2) :=\inf \{ |x_1 - x_2| : x_1\in \Sigma_1, x_2\in \Sigma_2\}$$
is positive and the minimum is attained. For every $(x_1, x_2)\in \Sigma_1\times \Sigma_2$ so that $|x_1-x_2| = d_0 (\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2)$, from the MCF equation we have $\partial_t |x_1 - x_2| \ge 0$. Thus $d_0(\Sigma_1^t, \Sigma_2^t)$ is non-decreasing in $t$, where $\Sigma^t_i$ are the MCF with $\Sigma_i^0 = \Sigma_i$, $i=1,2$. But since $\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2$ are both self-shrinkers, we see that $d_0(\Sigma_1^t, \Sigma_2^t)$ is strictly decreasing if $d_0(\Sigma_1, \Sigma_2)>0$. Thus we have arrived at a contradiction.

Comment: This answer is great. I just wanted to add that Imanen (unpublished) has shown that you can generalize this argument to apply even when both shrinkers are non-compact (just properly immersed) or singular etc. We wrote this up here https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.14344.pdf#page=65 (see Appendix C, specifically Corollary C.4). I find the result very amazing (and the proof is quite neat).